# How do you delete a room on chat?

Tags: support, chat

I created a test room on chat, but I can't see how to delete it.

Comment: that's because you can't :) we're not sure yet under what circumstances a non-moderator should be allowed to delete a room

Comment: @balpha even as a moderator, I can't seem to find a mechanism for deleting a room

Comment: @balpha: Talking about deleted rooms, what a certain room deleted recently?

Comment: @kyle I've posted about that in the moderator room

Comment: yes , chats should be deleted for the same reason as a comment is deleted. By the same person who wrote the chat. SE should state the reason why a chat is not allowed to be delete

Comment: @balpha They created the room... Shouldn't they be allowed to delete it?

Comment: @balpha can I ask you as a moderator to delete [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/38243/remote-sensing-and-photogrammetry-proposal)? I wanted to create it in area51 but it was accidentally created in stack overflow

Comment: @sepideh Done, but you needn't worry about these in general. Unused rooms are auto-deleted.

Comment: If only moderators can delete a chat room then there should be a system for chat room delete request.

Comment: comments aren't deleted after a period of time why should chat rooms

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Only moderators can delete rooms at the moment.

We're still working out the details on room-level actions.

Comment: How can I inform the moderators to delete a certain chat room?

Comment: Still no reply to this comment. Hello, can anyone hear me...?

Comment: So I had a chat room [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114124/discussion-between-rob-and-honey) but then it was automatically closed after 7 days and I can't even access the history. Is there anyway for me to access the history of it? Or as a general question does this mean that whatever that goes to a chat, is likely to be deleted very soon and I'd better save whatever I want to save from it?

Comment: Still? We should at least be able to request deletion of a room we made, that is, set a flag to call a mod's attention to it

Comment: Still? I accidentally created one...atleast a warning ?

Answer (score 38):

Provided that the room had less than 15 messages or fewer than 2 users that posted, [it will get deleted automatically](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention) if it is inactive for 7 days. You thus don't have to do anything (other than not post) to get it deleted.

If you need to ensure deletion of a room you own, and you have at least 1,000 [chat reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160292/377214), you could set the chat room permissions to Gallery, to make sure that others don't post and keep it alive.

Comment: How long does that take?

Comment: Not 14 days? Or does it get frozen, then deleted or?

Comment: What if the room has been frozen for at least a year and still hasn't been deleted? Is there a way I can request deletion of a room?