# Is it possible for the owner of a chat room that has been frozen, to edit or delete it?

Tags: support, chat, frozen-rooms

Is this functionality available? If not, has it been considered already?

Comment: I seem to have full control of my contributions elsewhere on the site - including the ability to, to a point, edit them and/or remove them. I think that's a good thing, since it allows for self - moderation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only mods and developers can operate on frozen chat rooms, and only they can [delete rooms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57099/how-do-you-delete-a-room-on-chat/57127#57127) (that answer is a year old, but I don't think it's inaccurate). This holds true even if you're an owner of the room.

Here on Meta, I can read the contents of frozen and deleted rooms (assuming the room isn't private), but that's it.

I think this behaviour is appropriate -- moderators should have ultimate control over this state of a chat room. If a room owner was allowed to override this, that would be akin to allowing a post owner to override a moderator lock on that post, which doesn't make sense from the perspective of moderation.

The only thing that might be a bit annoying is the auto-freeze after a week of inactivity. But on balance, I think that's alright to keep the chat room list cleaned up.

Comment: Do moderators get to decide, elsewhere on the site, whether my contributions should remain on the site or be deleted (and override my judgement)? Maybe a more appropriate functionality would be to "edit or remove my own contributions to a chat-room"

Comment: Yes, they do. They have the ability to lock posts, which prevents any kind of modification, including deletion/undeletion. If you can't trust the mods, who can you trust on the site?

Comment: I can easily see a post with 25 answers getting locked, where it contains comments or responses buried in its thread, which the poster might find embarrassing or otherwise not want to have around anymore, and want removed.

Comment: It's up to the mod's discretion. FYI: it's rarer to see, but individual answers can be locked as well.