# What should I do with an unused chat room?

Tags: support, chat

I have created a chat room, but before I invited the person who I wanted to talk to, he created another room.

We used his chat room, and mine is now unused, empty, and I am the only person who joined it. I've read that [only moderators can delete rooms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57099/how-do-you-delete-a-room-on-chat). What should I do with mine? Is there a way to ask a moderator to delete it?

Comment: so I don't have to bother about it? just forget it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Chat FAQ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#retention)

> Rooms not worth retaining which are inactive for 7 days will be deleted.

So just forget about it. Without any activity, the room will soon be gone.