# How to request to delete my chat room?

Tags: discussion, chat

I have read some post about how to delete chat room. Now I have some questions about this.

1. If I have created a room and there are more than two users are logged in and posted couple of messages. Then how this room get deleted if it was inactive from more than 1 week?
2. Can I send request to moderator to delete that room?
3. If more than two users from same region are talking in their language related to Application Programming. Then how can moderator know that it is On-topic chat.

Comment: Can down voter give reason?

Comment: @Nimesh, can you un-accept my answer ? This question is duplicate, so we should delete answer & question.

Comment: There is no need to do that.

Comment: @Bart, but what is the meaning of keeping a duplicate ques/answer with lots of downvotes.

Comment: It might make you happier to see it gone. But there is no explicit need for deletion.

Comment: How can you say **Can I send request to moderator to delete that room?** this question is duplicate of marked question?

Comment: @Nimesh, You may keep accepting my answer, As Bart said, There is no need to delete this post.

Comment: @Nimesh Are you telling me you don't know how to contact a moderator? Because the answers to 1 and 2 are simply "contact a moderator" and "yes". And question 3 is on a completely different topic, which should most likely not be part of the same question, unless you have a specific purpose for it in this context. So all in all the dupe is fine.

Comment: @Bart My first two questions are just related to answer of dupe question. In my first question I have mentioned that there are **more than two users** are logged in and **posted couple of messages**. According to [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/163963/252964) in dupe question. 'if **fewer than 2 users** then room will be deleted automatically'. My second question is related to [Jeff Atwood Answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57127/252964) only moderator can delete room. And the 3rd question is totally different.

Comment: You shouldn't be asking multiple questions in a single question. The third one seems entirely unrelated, so there is no point in having it. The other ones are simply answered by "contact a moderator" and I'm pretty certain you know how to do that.

Comment: Ok, that means I should delete this question because, I got my answer that I can **contact a moderator**.

Comment: Once again, there is absolutely no need to delete this question at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the answers,

1. Moderators can delete the room, if the room is getting lots of chat flags or if they found that chat room is not helpful.
2. Yes, you can send request to moderator. Flag any of the chat message with `flag for moderator` option.

   [image]
3. Users are allow to talk in their local language. If another user from same region found them doing off-topic chat then he/she may flag the message and report to moderator.

Comment: Whats the reason for downvote ?

Comment: same here. Who down voted can explain?

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian, closing & deleting a chat room both are different thing. Closing happens automatically after a certain period of inactivity in a chat room. While if you want to delete a chat room, then you should contact a moderator.

Comment: @Kedarnath Closing and deleting are definitely different, yes. But generally speaking, we're not going to delete a chatroom just because the creator happens to want it deleted. We'd really only do so for some major issue.