# Should I delete my own chatroom when done?

Tags: support, chat

I opened up my first chatroom for help on a question. It can be found [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46007/discussion-for-chmod-770). Now I'm wondering, is it my responsibility to delete the chatroom? What is the proper etiquette?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57127/245360) you can't. And even if you could, you shouldn't. Rooms are frozen when inactive. No need to delete them. If the room has little activity, it will be [deleted automatically](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention).